# loop with array stops

Tags: ios, arrays, loops

I have 2 arrays I am trying to get the matching idcodes.  But my array stops when it finds a matching idcode.  Is there any way to find all the matching id codes?

```
    NSArray *IDCodeArray = @[@29, @30, @31, @45];
    NSArray *dataArray = @[
                   @{
                       @"IDCode" : @5,
                       @"dateEnd" : @"04/08/2016",
                       @"dateStart" : @"04/08/2016"
                   },
                   @{
                       @"IDCode" : @30,
                       @"dateEnd" : @"04/09/2016",
                       @"dateStart" : @"04/09/2016"

                   },
                   @{
                       @"IDCode" : @55,
                       @"dateEnd" : @"04/10/2016",
                       @"dateStart" : @"04/10/2016"
                   },
                   @{
                       @"IDCode" : @29,
                       @"dateEnd" : @"04/11/2016",
                       @"dateStart" : @"04/11/2016"
                    },
                   @{
                       @"IDCode" : @30,
                       @"dateEnd" : @"04/11/2016",
                       @"dateStart" : @"04/11/2016"
                    }                      
 ];

 NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


 // loop through each object using fast enumeration

 [IDCodeArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber *idcode, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

__block NSUInteger foundIndex = NSNotFound;

// loop through data array to find IDcode
foundIndex = [dataArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(NSDictionary  *dictObject, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

    // stop the loop if found
    NSUInteger IDCodeObject = [dictObject valueForKey:@"IDCode"];
    return (IDCodeObject.integerValue == idcode.integerValue);
    }];

// add object to result array if found
if(foundIndex != NSNotFound){
    [resultArray addObject:[dataArray objectAtIndex:foundIndex]];
}
}];

NSLog(@"Result Array : %@", resultArray);
```

my resultArray is not getting the second idcode 30.   This array could have several matching results, so it has to get all the matches not just stop at the first one.   Thanks

Comment: please note the 2 arrays can vary depending on the data i get.   The 2 arrays are just example.   Thanks.

Comment: You could use a `NSPredicate` to do that: NSArray * resultArray = `[dataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"IDCode IN %@", IDCodeArray]]`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`[NSArray indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:) rather than `[NSArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:]`, in order to return multiple results rather than just one.

Answer (score 1):

As @Larme points out, using a predicate will be an ideal solution.

Try this -

```
   NSArray* matches = [dataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"IDCode IN %@", IDCodeArray]];
```